# Highcharts read data from XML throught attributes

Tags: xml, highcharts

I have small problem with reading data from XML.

**XML files**

```
<user name="Name1" status="online" ip="0.0.0.0">
     <stats>
       <cwok>201</cwok>
       <cwnok>0</cwnok>
       <cwignore>0</cwignore>
     </stats>
</user>
```

**Highcharts script to read data from XML **

```
// Load the data from the XML file
   $.get('oscamapi.html?part=userstats', function(xml) {

// Split the lines
   var $xml = $(xml);

// push series
   $xml.find('user').each(function(i, series) {
   var seriesOptions = {
   name: $(series).find('name').text(),
   data: []
    };

// push data points
   $(series).find('stats cwok').each(function(i, point) {
   seriesOptions.data.push(
   parseInt($(point).text())
   );
   });

// add it to the options
   options.series.push(seriesOptions);
    });
   var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
   });
   });
```

I need to get value attribute *name* in element *user* from XML.

I think the problem is somewhere here:

```
 var seriesOptions = {
    name: $(series).find('name').text(),
    data: []
 };
```

Do you help me please.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you would like to have line or other chart, but I prepare simple example with scatter series, and one point, which value is get grom "cwok". In case when you would like to have more points, you need more cwok items.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var options = {
  chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type:'scatter'
  },
  series: []
  };

  $.get('data.xml', function(xml) {
// Split the lines
  var $xml = $(xml);
  console.log(xml);

  // push categories
  $xml.find('stats cwok').each(function(i, data) {

    var seriesOptions = {

            data: []
    };

    seriesOptions.data.push(

      parseInt($(data).text())

    );

    options.series.push(seriesOptions);
  });

  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out how to get value from attribute "name" . Thanks for your answer :-)

```
var seriesOptions = {
    name: $(series).attr('name'),
    data: []
};
```

Answer (score 0):

But now I have other problem. I dont know how to get value from cwok from XML each 1 second

**XML Files**

```
<user name="Name1" status="online" ip="0.0.0.0">
 <stats>
   <cwok>100</cwok>
   <cwnok>0</cwnok>
   <cwignore>0</cwignore>
 </stats>
</user>
<user name="Name2" status="online" ip="0.0.0.0">
 <stats>
   <cwok>200</cwok>
   <cwnok>0</cwnok>
   <cwignore>0</cwignore>
 </stats>
</user>
```

**Highcharts script to read data from XML**

```
 // Load the data from the XML file
 $.get('oscamapi.html?part=userstats', function(xml) {

 // Split the lines
 var $xml = $(xml);

 // push series
 $xml.find('user').each(function(i, series) {
 var seriesOptions = {
 name: $(series).attr('name'),
 data: []
 };

// push data points
$(series).find('stats cwok').each(function(i, point) {
seriesOptions.data.push(
parseInt($(point).text())
);
});

// add it to the options
options.series.push(seriesOptions);
});
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
});
```

Thanks for your idea and help